# Meteor app crashes with unknown error code

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My meteor application crashes with the below error code. Don't know what the reason is. Can anyone help me?

```log
W20230417-16:03:36.416(6)? (STDERR) 11: 0xd4aa90
v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawOneByteString(int,
v8::internal::AllocationType)
[/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.11.0.1y0rrz1.a9ef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
W20230417-16:03:36.416(6)? (STDERR) 12: 0xd50d9d
v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char
const> const&, v8::internal::AllocationType)
[/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.11.0.1y0rrz1.a9ef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
W20230417-16:03:36.417(6)? (STDERR) 13: 0xbd1ac2
v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType,
int)
[/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.11.0.1y0rrz1.a9ef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
W20230417-16:03:36.417(6)? (STDERR) 14: 0xb1e7e9 
[/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.11.0.1y0rrz1.a9ef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
W20230417-16:03:36.417(6)? (STDERR) 15: 0xa169b1 
[/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.11.0.1y0rrz1.a9ef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
W20230417-16:03:36.418(6)? (STDERR) 16: 0x13e0ced 
[/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.11.0.1y0rrz1.a9ef++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node]
```

I tried lots of thing and google on internet. I reset meteor app. Then again install all node-modules but the problem still persists.

Comment: re "I've tried lots of things": Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. "Lots of things" is not particularly helpful, unless you want to know that you'll need to do "something else" ;)

Comment: Can you isolate the function on which this error occurs? If so, please add it's code here and some info (Meteor release, server vs client vs mobile).